# React explicitly don't render component inside html <code>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I render a component inside a HTML `<code>` element just as a text?

```
<code>
  <DesktopHeader>
    <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
  </DesktopHeader>
</code>
```

In my situation it renders my component again but I want to use it inside a documentation to just show how to pass props to a component.

Comment: you can put it inside backticks and make it a string.

Comment: This does unfortunately not work.

Comment: What do you mean by *inside a documentation*?

Comment: I am rendering a component and underneath I want to show the `code` for the component. Like it's done with Storybook JS.

Comment: You could use images like this instead though I don't know if thats what you're looking for https://carbon.now.sh/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a perfect matchup for what you intend to do but you can escape your markups with `&lt;` for `<`, `&gt;` for `>`, `&quot;` for `"` (quotes), and also `&nbsp;` for   (spaces).

So it will become something like this:

```html
<code>
&lt;DesktopHeader&gt;<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;a href=&quot;/projects&quot;&gt;Projects&lt;/a&gt;<br/> &lt;/DesktopHeader&gt;
</code>
```

**NOTE:** Generally every character with an UTF-8 code above 127 is not interchangeable between the "normal" Western ISO-8859-1 encoding and UTF-8. But to creating HTML markups knowing these three (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&nbsp;`, and `&quot;`) would be enough. I'm also found a [link](http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html) that can be useful for generating markups automatically.